# NodeJS Socket.io variable undefined

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am making my first chat app with Node and Socket.io.  So far everything is working correctly except when i try to output the client.nickname variable.

**index.html**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.on('connect', function(data){
      $('#status').html("Connected!");
      var nickname = prompt("Whats ur name?");
      socket.on('join', nickname);
    });
    $('#submit-btn').click(function(){
      var msg = $('#input_text').val();
      socket.emit('messages',msg);
    });

    socket.on('messages', function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
```

**app.js**

```
io.on('connection', function(client){
  client.on('join', function(name){
    client.nickname = name;
  });
  client.on('messages', function(data){
    var nickname = client.nickname;
    client.broadcast.emit('messages', nickname +": " + data);
    client.emit('messages', nickname + ": " + data);
  });
});
```

My console outputs:
undefined : The correct message.

It should output:
Kyle(or what ever is entered in the prompt): The correct message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to emit data to the 'join' handler.

For example:

**index.html**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('connect', function(data){
  $('#status').html("Connected!");
  var nickname = prompt("Whats ur name?");
  socket.emit('join', nickname); // change this line from socket.on('join', nickname);
});
$('#submit-btn').click(function(){
  var msg = $('#input_text').val();
  socket.emit('messages',msg);
});
```

**app.js**

```
io.on('connection', function(client){
  client.on('join', function(name){
    client.nickname = name;
});
```

**Note this code was not tested.**

Comment: Thanks!  I needed to change  socket.on('join', nickname); to socket.emit('join', nickname); in the index.html

Comment: Yeah I updated my answer to a clearer example but it looks like you already got it=).